# PHP Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256

Tags: php, apache-http-server

I am getting a constant error of

```
 mod_fcgid: stderr: Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256
```

from my apache logs.
I am wondering why PHP is complaining since the hash module is installed.

My PHP info:

```
 php -v
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze17 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 23 2013 15:06:16)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH
# php -m | grep hash
hash
mhash
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261606/unknown-algorithm-expected-hmac-sha256-spam-in-logs

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Not related to that issue! I googled that before and this is not related to Facebook SDK but another script. Plus there is no solution addressing PHP configuration in that issue

Comment: Oh, okay. What are you running on the server?

Comment: Running a script named INDEXU 7.4 . Developers are slow in responsind.

Comment: I am just trying to know if a module is missing in my PHP or not. Apparently the message leads to hash module which is installed.

Comment: You're not missing anything. Part of that application is simply causing output to `stderr` which is logged in the logfile. Indexu has "Facebook integration" which is probably causing this message. You can see this error message right here https://github.com/WarFox/socioall/blob/master/fb_data.php#L13 Indexu probably uses this project.